# In Spark Streaming how to process old data and delete processed Data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are running a Spark streaming job that retrieves files from a directory (using textFileStream). 
One concern we are having is the case where the job is down but files are still being added to the directory. 
Once the job starts up again, those files are not being picked up (since they are not new or changed while the job is running) but we would like them to be processed.

1) Is there a solution for that? Is there a way to keep track what files have been processed and can we "force" older files to be picked up?

2) Is there a way to delete the processed files?

Comment: It's surprising that this is an exactly same question (literally word by word) as asked on this two year old spark-user mailing list. Does the reply of that mail chain answer your doubt? https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201502.mbox/%3CCAPpNfpU_jPRGMU_wF3MJyo1M3fC5y0fn1ebVXOUTj8UbRd=6yg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article below pretty much covers all your questions.

https://blog.yanchen.ca/2016/06/28/fileinputdstream-in-spark-streaming/

*1) Is there a solution for that? Is there a way to keep track what files have been processed and can we "force" older files to be picked up?*

Stream reader initiates batch window using the system clock when a job/application is launched. Apparently all the files created before would be ignored. Try enabling **checkpointing**.

*2) Is there a way to delete the processed files?*

Deleting files might be unnecessary. If checkpointing works, the files not being processed are identified by Spark. If for some reason the files are to be deleted, implement a custom input format and reader (please refer article) to capture the file name and use this information as appropriate. But I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: The site "blog.yanchen.im" no longer exists.

Comment: How to get processed files name?

Comment: @Charlie木匠 see my comment below

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question,

It is now possible in Spark 3. You can use "cleanSource" option for readStream.

Thanks to documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html and this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM7T34Uu2Gg.

After searching for many hours, finally got the solution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to delete the processed files?*

In my experience, I can´t get to work the checkpointing feature so I had to delete/move the processed files that have entered each batch.

The way for getting those files is a bit tricky, but basically we can say that they are ancestors (dependencies) of the current `RDD`. What I use then, is a recursive method that crawls that structure and recovers the names of the `RDD`s that begin with `hdfs`.

```
  /**
    * Recursive method to extract original metadata files involved in this batch.
    * @param rdd Each RDD created for each batch.
    * @return All HDFS files originally read.
    */
   def extractSourceHDFSFiles(rdd: RDD[_]): Set[String] = {

     def extractSourceHDFSFilesWithAcc(rdd: List[RDD[_]]) : Set[String] = {

      rdd match {
        case Nil => Set()
        case head :: tail => {
          val name = head.toString()
          if (name.startsWith("hdfs")){
            Set(name.split(" ")(0)) ++ extractSourceHDFSFilesWithAcc(head.dependencies.map(_.rdd).toList) ++ extractSourceHDFSFilesWithAcc(tail)
          }
          else {
            extractSourceHDFSFilesWithAcc(head.dependencies.map(_.rdd).toList) ++ extractSourceHDFSFilesWithAcc(tail)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    extractSourceHDFSFilesWithAcc(rdd.dependencies.map(_.rdd).toList)
  }
```

So, in the `forEachRDD` method you can easily invoke it:

```
stream.forEachRDD(rdd -> {

     val filesInBatch = extractSourceHDFSFiles(rdd)
    logger.info("Files to be processed:")

    // Process them

    // Delete them when you are done
})
```