# Apache Spark/AWS EMR and tracking of processed files

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have AWS S3 folder where the big number of JSON files is stored. I need to ETL these files with AWS EMR over Spark and store the transformation into AWS RDS.

I have implemented the Spark job for this purpose on Scala and everything is working fine. I plan to execute this job once a week.

From time to time the external logic can add a new files to AWS S3 folder so the next time when my Spark job is starting I'd like to process only the new(unprocessed) JSON files.

Right now I don't know where to store the information about the processed JSON files so the Spark job can decide what files/folders to process. Could you please advise me what is the best practice(and how) to track this changes with Spark/AWS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is spark streaming job, `checkpointing` is what you are looking for, it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677772/in-spark-streaming-how-to-process-old-data-and-delete-processed-data).

- `Checkpoint`ing stores the state information (ie offsets etc) in hdfs/s3 bucket, so when the job is started again, spark picks up only the un-processed files. Checkpointing offers better fault tolerance in case of failures as well, as state is handled automatically by spark itself.
- Again checkpointing only works in the streaming mode of spark job.

Comment: Thank! How about batch? In case of the batch job this information about the processed files must be handled outside of Spark?

Comment: I have not seen any out of the box spark feature, which client are you using for reading from s3, can you check if that client provides a ability to take in a `start-after` as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html)  so that you can get the last processed key from previous run of the job and cache it.